# Delete all html Tags out of an excel sheet while preserving text inbetween

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex

Hi i have an excel sheet that was exported directly form a Database. This includes various strings some of which are html tags. I want to delete all the link tags example

```
(<a href="mylink" target="_blank">
```

but keep all the other strings intact. I was trying to do this with a find and replace but i cannot figure out a Regex that will do this and also work in excel. 
I have scoured the net but was not able to find a solution to this.

If i do this

```
<a href*>
```

it will delete almost all the content of the spreadsheet because it goes to the last closing tag it can find.
Is there a way to redo my search so that it gets the next closing tag and not the last one?

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest i.e. only, good way I know of is by use of Lynx, the old text mode web browser:
`lynx --dump URL_or_HTML-file`
 - but then, you need to find a way to run it on Windows (e.g. cygwin, or WSL).

Oh... one more thing: You should realize; what you're asking for is essentially a web browser in its full glory.

lynx is that, even with its inherent limitations and shortcomings.

Example:

```
$ lynx --dump www.google.se

   Sök [1]Bilder [2]Maps [3]Play [4]YouTube [5]Nyheter [6]Gmail [7]Drive
   [8]Mer »
   [9]Webbhistorik | [10]Inställningar | [11]Logga in

   Google

     _______________________________________________________
   Sök på Google  Jag har tur    [12]Avancerad sökning
      [13]Språkverktyg

   Google på: [14]English

   [15]Annonsera med Google     [16]Företagslösningar     [17]+Google
   [18]Allt om Google     [19]Google.com

                    © 2019 - [20]Sekretess - [21]Villkor

References

   1. http://www.google.se/imghp?hl=sv&tab=wi
   2. http://maps.google.se/maps?hl=sv&tab=wl
   3. https://play.google.com/?hl=sv&tab=w8
   4. http://www.youtube.com/?gl=SE&tab=w1
   5. http://news.google.se/nwshp?hl=sv&tab=wn
   6. https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm
   7. https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo
   8. https://www.google.se/intl/sv/about/products?tab=wh
   9. http://www.google.se/history/optout?hl=sv
  10. http://www.google.se/preferences?hl=sv
  11. https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=sv&passive=true&continue=http://www.google.se/
  12. http://www.google.se/advanced_search?hl=sv&authuser=0
  13. http://www.google.se/language_tools?hl=sv&authuser=0
  14. http://www.google.se/setprefs?sig=0_aqHPilDIYLLsVqHCw93WtOpJW0k=&hl=en&source=homepage&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifvrHulZHgAhXGjywKHVziBaIQ2ZgBCAQ
  15. http://www.google.se/intl/sv/ads/
  16. http://www.google.se/intl/sv/services/
  17. https://plus.google.com/103822168634868962761
  18. http://www.google.se/intl/sv/about.html
  19. http://www.google.se/setprefdomain?prefdom=US&sig=K_KnzY40g4UTDMelz-_ON-EEbQQGM=
  20. http://www.google.se/intl/sv/policies/privacy/
  21. http://www.google.se/intl/sv/policies/terms/
```